# Twig - Trying to split an array element

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, twig

Im looping over an array of objects, and then trying to split one of the elements, in this case I want to split the postcode on the space. Ie. 'AB1 1AB' should just be 'AB1' .

```
{% for result in resultset %}
            {{ result.postcode|split(' ') }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Throws me an 'array to string error'

Trying just:

```
{{ result.postcode[0] }}
```

Throws me a 'impossible to access key [0] on a string varaible' error.

and just doing:

```
{{ result.postcode }}
```

gives me no error, with the postcode displayed as `'AB1 1AB'`

Why does Twig think the string is an array when I try to split it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the official doc:

> The **split** filter splits a string by the given delimiter and
>   returns a **list of strings**:

```
{{ "one,two,three"|split(',') }}
{# returns ['one', 'two', 'three'] #}
```

So, taking your code, you could do something like:

```
{% for result in resultset %}
    {{ set myArray = result.postcode|split(' ') }}
    {{ myArray[0] }} {# Will output "AB1" #}
{% endfor %}
```

Source: [TWIG Split filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html)

Comment: I just figured this out myself (14 seconds after you posted this) Always the way. :) While this works, I don't really understand why. How is result.postcode considered an array, when it can be outputted as a string?

Comment: `result.postcode` is a `string`. But if you `split` it, the returned object is a `list of string`. So, if you take that into a variable (like myArray) you'll be able to display all the array values (the result of the split), which are `myArray[0] => "AB1"` and `myArray[1] => "1AB"`. I hope I've helped you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. From the Twig docs: **Internally, Twig uses the PHP explode** which - from the PHP docs - **Returns an array of strings** , not a **list of strings**. Confusing! There we go though.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but the real problem is that you asked `Twig` to display the result of your split using a `{{...}}` block. You should use the `{%...%}` block and `set` tag, as explained in the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation).

If you only want to display some part, you can use either `split` with `[first][2]` filter or [slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html).